# Are there any ways to skip data-loading lines while executing a script?

Tags: python

I have the following code section which loads a big file into a numpy array in Python,

```
from numpy import genfromtxt

data = genfromtxt("images.csv", delimiter=',', skip_header=1)
print(data.size)
```

Since the csv file is quite big, the execution time is also high. Is there a way, when I run this file, to skip these 3 lines of code so that I will not wait for the data to be loaded at every execution and additionally, the data will be the same?

Comment: "and additionally, the data will be the same" - so you'd like to load the data... without loading the data? If you don't want to load the data, you can comment out these lines, but then the script won't work if it requires the data.

Comment: Sorry. When I execute the code for the FIRST time, of course I will run these codes and data will get its value. However, when I execute the code for the second time, I want to skip it so that I will not have to wait for a long time and data will be the same.

Comment: Then you'll have to keep the Python REPL running. You can use Jupyter notebooks - they're specifically made for data exploration without rerunning the script every time you change it.

Comment: you can't skip it when you run in script (`python script.py`). System removes all data from memory at the end of script. And you can't make modifications in code when script is running. You may only run in Python REPL/Shell, IPython or Jupyter to have it all time in memory and make modification. But maybe you should use Google Colab to run it. It may run faster on Google servers, but it need to upload data on Google Colab server or Google Drive.